# Jenkins SonarQube Plugin: "javac: invalid target release: 11"

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I'm trying to automate SonarQube checks via Jenkins right now. Jenkins already builds & deploys my project automatically, however when I'm executing the SonarQube plugin I get the above error.

I know what the issue is in theory: javac doesn't use a Java 11 JDK to compile my project. I can't figure out why however, since I installed Java 11 on my server (Ubuntu) via apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk (previously java 8 was installed)

Result of both java + javac -version:
javac 11.0.14

Result of mvn -v:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.14, vendor: Ubuntu
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-210-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Maven home is the same as set in Jenkins-Config and the script in Jenkinsfile uses that Maven config.
JAVA_HOME also points to 11, although that shouldn't be relevant.

pom.xml:

```
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
```

Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
  stage('SCM') {
    checkout scm
  }
  stage('SonarQube Analysis') {
    def mvn = tool 'Maven';
    withSonarQubeEnv() {
      sh "${mvn}/bin/mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=[key] -Dsonar.projectName=[projectname]"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm out of ideas on what's still wrong. At this point I assume somehow there is still a setting somewhere hidden that points to the old Java 8 SDK, but I can't figure out where.